# How to style filepicker.io iframe

Tags: filepicker.io

I am using:

```
filepicker.pick({ container: "filepicker_iframe" ...)
```

to open a `filepicker` dialog in given `iframe`. Is it possible to somehow style elements in `iframe` to match my site styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can provide a css file to include inside the iframe on your developer portal

Comment: Ha. Could we maybe get a copy of the default CSS file so we know what the class names are? I see where input the URL's for my CSS files, but have no idea how to compose them because I have no reference. Am I missing something in the docs or are the docs missing something?

I'm happy to hand over my $100 a month, but in the first hour I've noticed some serious holes in your docs.

Comment: We're building out a theme roller and better documentation to make the process easier, so for now I can only give the rather unsatisfying answer of recommending that you use the web inspector to get the CSS selector path of what you want to modify.